# Making Terminal bash auto-complete stop at ambiguous character and display all possible options

Tags: terminal, bash, auto-complete

The behavior I see happening is that when I type something partially and hit TAB, if there are multiple files/commands that match what I had typed in, only the first one is displayed. Further TAB hits result in other matches being shown. Instead, I want the auto-completion to fill till the first ambiguous character and then if I hit TAB again, display *all* possible choices (as in say Ubuntu terminal). This is what I have in my .inputrc:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on 
TAB: menu-complete
```

The show-all-if-ambiguous seems to be what I am looking for, but it doesn't seem to work for me.

I actually want the behavior that this member doesn't:

[Skip first terminal beep and to display ambiguous filename expansions](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/173286/skip-first-terminal-beep-and-to-display-ambiguous-filename-expansions)

I like hearing the first BEEP (or stop) and then typing in some more characters to fix the ambiguity.

Comment: I think you need to disable menu complete.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to comment from mtklr. [Many](http://www.macdaddynews.com/2014/07/12/enable-tab-completion-mac-os-x-terminal/) [web](http://osxdaily.com/2012/08/02/improve-tab-completion-in-mac-os-x-terminal/) pages that talk about Mac OS X Terminal auto-complete asks you to add the 3 lines I mention in my question. But if you want behavior as on say Ubuntu, you need just the first 2 lines:

```
set completion-ignore-case on
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

**Do not add TAB: menu-complete**

Answer (score 0):

On Big Sur, I got the best results with just the:

```
set show-all-if-ambiguous on
```

Tab completion would work without it, but would not show the available options if there was more than one completion.